# MobileSubstrate: How to make an object globally accessible

Tags: iphone, global, ivar, springboard, cydia-substrate

I'm currently working on a MobileSubstrate extension using substrate.h and I need an object to be accessible from every bundle.

As far as I know (and I tried), if I just put a `static` variable inside the code this would only make the object accessible throughout the currently injected bundle (e.g. SpringBoard or any App).

So I wonder what's the best way to be able to access the same object from every App (bundle)?

I had the idea to add an instance variable to the `SpringBoard` class, but apparently I can't  call `class_addIvar()` on an existing class.

Any help is greatly appreciated.